# Issues with UIWebView and HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: http, uiwebview, authorization

I've scoured the web on how to do basic http auth in a uiwebview.  I've tried it all and am getting inconsistent results no matter what I do.  Sometimes auth works, sometimes it doesn't.  It's driving me up the wall and I'd love some help!

Here's the relevant code.  I always get an auth challenge, but the webview doesn't always load (I basically time out waiting for webViewDidFinishLoad - no errors).  Any ideas?

```
/*
 Load a webview
*/
- (void)loadWebView
{
    NSLog(@"loading webview");
    if( _webView == NULL ){
        // UIWebView initialization
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        _webView.hidden = TRUE;
    }

    // set up webview request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:30];

    // load the request
    [_webView setDelegate:self];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];

    // add ourselves as delegate to connection events so we can authenticate
    (void)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}


/**
 authenticates against HTTP basic authorization
 */
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    //receive a authenticate and challenge with the user credential
    NSLog(@"got auth challenge.  Authenticating...");
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic] &&
        [challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        NSURLCredential *credentail = [NSURLCredential
                                       credentialWithUser:AUTH_USERNAME
                                       password:AUTH_PASS
                                       persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Message" message:@"Invalid credentails" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

/**
 store auth credentials
 */
- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    NSLog(@"using credential storage");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass authentication in url instead of request header
please try instead of BASE_URL:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@//%@:%@@%@",@"http:",userName,password,myUrl]
```

Comment: OP is specifically asking for basic auth not a work around for it.